# macro expansion in C/C++

Tags: c++, macros

I have this macro from someone's code:

```
#define Q_DEF_PROTOTYPE( Type, Name ) Type (*Name)

#define COPY_FP( pDest, pSrc ) (*((void**)(&(pDest)))) = ((void*)(pSrc))

#define LIB_QUERY(lib_handle, proc)  dlsym(lib_handle, proc)

#define Q_DEF_PROTOTYPE( Type, Name ) \
COPY_FP( p->Name, LIB_QUERY( g_library, STRINGIZE(FUNC(Name)) ) ); \
void dummy_##Name
```

Not sure, what "void dummy_##Name" does? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Comment: @chris, why not just post that as an answer and add the text "that's called token concatenation"?

Comment: @chris: Thanks, I understood that. But say, "Name" is "func_name", then ""void dummy_##Name" becomes "void dummy_func_name". This doesn't appear meaningful to me. What does this exactly translate to? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It replace the `##Name` with the value of Name parameter as string.

`Q_DEF_PROTOTYPE(myType, objectName) => void dummy_objectName`

Comment: But will this not give compilation errors? And what kind of a declaration is - void dummy_objectName? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I guess no, it just defines a void variable. If he uses like Q_DEF_PROTOTYPE(myType, objectName); (; is important), then it will work and the last line is void dummy_objectName;